# HAVING statement causes Invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, having

New here and beginner with SQL. I'm designing an accounting program in Excel, using SQLs in VBA to pull data from an Access database.
The point of the SQL below is to list the invoices that have NOT been (entirely) paid yet.
The fields are as follows:

- reference: the reference number of the invoice (when i get an invoice, I book that I have to pay it. When I pay it a few days later (different db record), it has the same reference number)
- amount_credit: the amount that needs to be paid
- amount_debit: the amount that has been paid (so far - it's possible it's paid in multiple fractions and so far only partially paid)
- account_debit and account_credit must have value 52 (which is "Accounts payable")

When for a specific reference the total amount_credit = the total amount_debit, the invoice with that reference has been fully paid, and it should not be listed.

My sql is as follows:

```
WITH p AS 
(
  SELECT reference, 
    SUM(IIF(account_debit = 52, amount_debit, 0)) as paidamount, 
    SUM(IIF(account_credit = 52, amount_credit, 0)) as totalamount 
  FROM Transactions t 
  WHERE account_debit = 52 OR account_credit = 52
  GROUP BY reference
) 
SELECT p.reference, p.paidamount, p.totalamount FROM p 
HAVING p.paidamount <> p.totalamount 
ORDER BY p.reference;
```

Everything works fine if I exclude the HAVING statement. Of course then it displays all the transactions (grouped by reference), including those that have been paid.
However the HAVING statement triggers Error code "Invalid SQL statement;expected "Delete, Insert, Procedure, Select, or...).

Can you tell what is causing this and how I can make this work? Thank you in advance.

Rudy

Edit: current coding is as follows and is very close but still shows some results where amount_credit=amount_debit

`SELECT reference, SUM(IIF(account_debit = 52, amount_debit, 0)) as paidamount, SUM(IIF(account_credit = 52, amount_credit, 0)) as totalamount FROM Transactions t  WHERE t.account_debit = 52 OR t.account_credit = 52  GROUP BY t.reference HAVING SUM(IIF(account_debit = 52, amount_debit, 0)) <> SUM(IIF(account_credit = 52, amount_credit, 0))`

Comment: There's no `GROUP BY` in the outer query so there's no reason to use `HAVING`. You can use `WHERE` instead. On the other hand, if you *don't* use a CTE you'll be able to use `HAVING` right after the `GROUP BY clause

Comment: You need `where p.paidamount <> p.totalamount `

Comment: Then how do I filter out the completed transactions (those where paidamount = totalamount)? I also tried using WHERE instead of HAVING but then it says "No value given for one or more required parameters".

Comment: Ok. First should I place the WHERE (or HAVING) in the outer query or in the inner query?

Comment: In the outer query. Or you can remove the outer query completely and use `HAVING SUM(IIF(account_debit = 52, amount_debit, 0)) <> SUM(IIF(account_credit = 52, amount_credit, 0))` in the inner query. In other words, `HAVING` needs a `GROUP BY` in the same scope, and cannot refer to the calculations in the `SELECT`

Comment: Use a where clause in the outer result set

Comment: @Charlieface: very close to the desired result. For some reason there are still some results  displayed where amount_debit equals amount_credit (invoices that were fully paid and should not be shown). Updated code to current version in first post.

Comment: Possibly rounding errors? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: No rounding errors. What they DO have in common is that the invoices were paid over multiple payments. Eg. invoice for $100 (amount_credit = 100) of which $80 was paid the next day and remaining $20 a few days later (SUM of amount_debit = 100). So it sums it correctly but somehow bypasses the HAVING condition

Comment: just picked this up and not seen your previous iterations - what's the significance of 52 please? If you're trying to filter the CTE by this SUM(IIF(52...)) logic then it needs to be in a having in the CTE and not in the WHERE.

Comment: There are many accounts (different costs, income, bank account, etc...) which all have a numeric identifier. '52' is the identifier of "Accounts payable". When I get an invoice the debit account is for example account 13 (rental costs) and credit account is 52 (accounts payable) - it's not paid yet. When I pay, the debit account is 52 (accounts payable) and the credit account is 1 (bank account) - accounts payable is counter-booked (cleared) and the invoice is paid (deducted from the bank account). Both transactions have the same reference. Total debit and credit amounts are equal.